# Select and count query from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, count

I must retrive all those who have sent messages to a given user and if the messages have not been read, return the number.
I have two tables

```
users

| id_user| username | status |
|    1   |   user1  |   yes  |
|    2   |   user2  |   yes  |
|    3   |   user3  |   yes  |

messages

| id_message |id_sender|id_dest|    message  | read |
|     1      |    1    |   2   |   some text | yes  |
|     2      |    3    |   2   |   some text |  no  |
|     3      |    2    |   1   |   some text |  no  |
```

and I have this query

```
select id_sender,username, count(distinct   id_message) as nr_messages
            FROM messages
            INNER JOIN users
            ON id_sender = id_user
            WHERE id_dest=$dest and status='yes'
            GROUP by id_sender
```

I can count the number of messages for each user but I can not know how many are unread. I must have a number if the messages are unread and 0 i the user do not have unread messages.
for example for user2

```
 sender: user3 (1 unread message)
 sender: user1 (0 unred message)
```

messages table is ~2000000 rows

Comment: I don't see `receiver_id` in the schema as you have in query.

Comment: Perhaps: `sum(case when read = 'yes' then 0 else 1 end)`...

Comment: Or shorthand mysql conditional sum as `sum(read <>'yes')`

Comment: yes my error I have update

Comment: @sgeddes I dont undestand your answer can you explain or make an example? thanks

Comment: I think you are going to need to `JOIN` your `GROUP BY` table back to the `users` table to make sure users with no dropped messages appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to count both read and unread at the same time, you can use conditional sum as

```
select 
m.id_sender,
u.username,
sum(m.`read` = 'yes') as read_messages,
sum(m.`read` <> 'yes') as unread_messages 
from messages m 
join users u on u.id_user = m.id_sender 
where m.id_dest = 2 
group by m.id_sender ;
```

For the above sample data you will get

```
+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
| id_sender | username | read_messages | unread_messages |
+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|         1 | user1    |             1 |               0 |
|         3 | user3    |             0 |               1 |
+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
```